# from pandas dataframe save csv file without double quotes

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, csv, export-to-csv, double-quotes

To save a csv file from pandas dataframe I have tried following way:

```
res.to_csv('seq_test.fa',header= False, index= False, sep = '\t', quoting = csv.QUOTE_NONE)
```

and this gives me following error:`need to escape, but no escapechar set`

If I don't use `quoting = csv.QUOTE_NONE` . I get output below way:

```
>His-ATG-1-1    33-35
"TGGGGTATAGCTCCATGGTAGAGCGCATGCCTATGAAGCGTGAGGTCCTGGGTTTGATCCCCAGAACCACAACCA
"   
>Pro-AGG-2-1    33-35
"GGCTTGTTGGTCTAGGGGTATGATTCTCACTTAGGGTGTGAGAGGTCCTGGGTTCAAATCTTGGACGAGTCCCCA
"   
>Lys-TTT-1-1    34-36
"GCCCGGATAGCTCAGTCGGTAGAGCATCAGACTTTTAATCTGAGGGTCCAGGGTTCAAGTCCCTGTTCGGGCGCCA
"   
>Ile-TAT-3-1    34-36
"GGTTCCATAGGGTAGTGGTTATCACATCTGCTTTATATGCAGAAGGTCCTGAGTTTGAGCCCCAGTGGAACTACCA
"
```

Here I don't want any double quotes in my output.
Can someone suggest me any possible way?
If anycase required I am using pandas version 0.17 on python 2.7

Answer (score 7):

```
 res.to_csv('seq_test.fa',header= False, index= False, sep = '\t', quoting = csv.QUOTE_NONE, escapechar = ' ')
```

Fill in the escapechar with whatever character is appropriate.

Reference: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html